# searborn annotate overwrites previous

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to loop through chunks of pandas dataframe and append chart to pdf. here is sample code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends import backend_pdf

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[a + + random.random() for a in range(12)] , 
                   'b':[ b + random.random() for b in range(12,24)]})
print(df)

chunk_size = 3 # number of rows in heatmap
n_chunks = len(df)//chunk_size  # number of pages in heatmap pdf

with backend_pdf.PdfPages('chart.pdf') as pdf_pages:    
    for e,(k,g) in enumerate(df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//chunk_size)):
        #print(k,g.shape)
        snsplot = sns.heatmap(g, annot=True,  cbar=False, linewidths=.5) #fmt="d",cmap="YlGnBu", 
        pdf_pages.savefig(snsplot.figure)
```

This code adds pages alright, but all the annotation from previous pages seems to be overlayed (preserved) in all the pages that follow.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `sns.heatmap` it is using `plt.gca()` so all of your plotting is going to the same `Axes` object (each loop might be getting slower too as all of the previous artists are rendered, but just occluded by the latest one).

I suggest something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
with backend_pdf.PdfPages('chart.pdf') as pdf_pages:    
    for e,(k,g) in enumerate(df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//chunk_size)):
        #print(k,g.shape)
        ax.cla()
        snsplot = sns.heatmap(g, annot=True,  cbar=False, linewidths=.5, ax=ax)
        pdf_pages.savefig(snsplot.figure)
```

Which passes in an `Axes` object so seaborn knows where to draw and explicitly clears it in each loop.